# @RequestBody is getting null values

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have created a simple REST service (POST). But when i call this service from postman @RequestBody is not receiving any values.

```
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@RestController
public class Add_Policy {
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/Add_Policy", headers = {
            "content-type=application/json" }, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Policy GetIPCountry( @RequestBody Policy policy) {

        System.out.println("Check value: " + policy.getPolicyNumber());
        return policy;

    }


}
```

My java Bean object is like below:

```
public class Policy {
    private String PolicyNumber;
    private String Type;
    private String Tenture;
    private String SDate;
    private String HName;
    private String Age;

    public String getPolicyNumber() {
        return PolicyNumber;
    }

    public void setPolicyNumber(String policyNumber) {
        PolicyNumber = policyNumber;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return Type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        Type = type;
    }

    public String getTenture() {
        return Tenture;
    }
```

System.out.println is printing a null as a value for PolicyNumber.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

JSON which i am passing in request body is

```
{
    "PolicyNumber": "123",
    "Type": "Test",
    "Tenture": "10",
    "SDate": "10-July-2016",
    "HName": "Test User",
    "Age": "10"
}
```

I have even set `Content-Type` to `application/json` in postman

Comment: Apply `@ResponseBody` to the output of the method not the method itself. Also include the `produces` header value if you're expecting JSON value.

Comment: Even if i make the response as void, values from the request is same null

Comment: `policy` itself wasn't null, are you sure that it contains `policyNumber` ?

Comment: All the values in the `Policy` object is revived as null. I have added a `tostring()` method  `policy` bean and checked this.

Comment: please could you show us your json request?

Comment: Try setting the first character of the properties in your JSON to lower case. Eg.
{
    "policyNumber": "123",
    "type": "Test",
    "tenture": "10",
    "sDate": "10-July-2016",
    "hName": "Test User",
    "age": "10"
}

Comment: Thanks @AmanSinghal it worked.. I changed all the keys' letters to lowercase. even `HName` to `hname`. But really dint understood this behavior of spring.

Comment: You need to follow camel case convention, setting name of all the properties in JSON would not help.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Try setting the first character of the properties in your JSON to lower case. Eg.

```
{
    "policyNumber": "123",
    "type": "Test",
    "tenture": "10",
    "sDate": "10-July-2016",
    "hName": "Test User",
    "age": "10"
}
```

Basically, Spring uses getter and setter to set the properties of the the bean object. And it takes the property of the JSON object, matches it with the setter of the same name. eg to set the policyNumber property it tries to find a setter with the name setpolicyNumber() in your bean class and use that to set the value of your bean object.

Comment: I had this problem because I forget to create getter and setter.

Comment: i still get that issue. My properties are all lowercase. It gets the object but with all nulls like that ```Task{id=0, teachingHours=null, surveillanceHours=null, proofReading=null, isActive=false, isValidated=false, candidateId=null, supervisorId=null}```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76879877/9172548

Answer (score 130):

Check the @RequestBody `import`,

wrong that will cause the problem in most cases.

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody;
```

to solve problem It should be

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
```

Comment: Isn't the import same in the question ?  Or provide more details to your answer

Comment: My problem was the import from swagger not springframework...

Comment: Yep. For me the import was from swagger. Ugh! Thanks for tip.

Comment: For me too the import was from swagger

Comment: same here on swagger getting in the way

Comment: Geesh, spent way too much time on this one. Thanks!

Comment: Ughh! Spend too much time. And I was thinking why `record` type is not working when I had another method where it was working fine. Even tried with POJO class.

Comment: my problem was I had note provided the getters and setters. Please make sure put getters and setters.

Comment: Swagger strikes again! Good thing I stumbled upon this before wasting even more time pulling my hair out

Answer (score 17):

Setter would have been missed. So, Object values do not get set.

Comment: Put this as a comment

Comment: for me it was getter that was missing

Answer (score 9):

Java convention demands the name of variable in a POJO (attribute of a class) must to be the first character in lowercase.

You have uppercase letters in your JSON properties, which is what is causing the failure.

Answer (score 8):

If you are not in power to change the JSON format and still want to fix this problem, try adding
`@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.UpperCamelCaseStrategy.class)`
annotation before your DTO (Policy in example) class.

Comment: it's deprecated now , but working

Answer (score 3):

I had lombok in my pom, and lombok annotations on my bean. I did not properly installed lombok with my STS yet, and had similar issue, my bean was not populated.

When I removed lombok annotations, my bean was properly populated.

Seems like a combination of lomboc not properly installed on STS + lomboc annotations on my bean.

Answer (score 3):

see spring PropertyNamingStrategy(UPPER_CAMEL_CASE,LOWER_CAMEL_CASE ,LOWER_CASE
etc...  defalult SNAKE_CASE).
Spring will auto change http contorller class parameter by naming strategy, which may be not consistant with your request json
take SNAKE_CASE as a ex, when "myToken" in java controller class, you client should send my_token instead of myToken

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

if you are using **Lombok Api** then there are no Getters and Setters publicly visible or available to the @**ResponseBody** and @**RequestBody** annotation.
That is why we read the **JSON request with null** values.

So you need to comment those @Getter, @Setter annotation to Receive JSON response and Read JSON request object and generate the same getters and setters.
Restart or Hot Load (using Spring-Boot-Devtools) server and it should work for sure.
You can still use your lombok api for other Entities or BO's.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from `lowerCamelCasing`, for me what additionally needed was applying `@JsonProperty(value="your expected JSON KEY name")` for each of the getter and setter methods and using `this` operator under the *POJO/Bean/DTO class*.

Sample Code:

```
@JsonProperty(value="policyNumber")
public void setPolicyNumber(String policyNumber) {
        this.policyNumber = policyNumber;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the annotation `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody` and not `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody`

Comment: You are sure in my case! Thanks!  :(

Answer (score 1):

In my case was a Lombok issue. I removed all the lombok annotations and created the constructor, setter and getter manually.

As an advise, I would also set the JSON to lowercase to follow the convention.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Lombok you need compileOnly and annotationProcessor
In my case I missed the 2nd one. So I got all null values

```
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, empty constructor must be defined.

```
public MyClass(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had  the  same  issue but  for  my case only one field was not  being  set. A log  on the  request body object showed it  was being  recieved as null. deleted getters and setters for  the field and autogenerated them  using  the IDE and  all worked fine.

I highly suspect a mismatch in the  getter and  setter definition can also  cause this

Answer (score 0):

I have been having this issue too, but the best way i solve mine was checking on spaces after the first quotes in every initialization of fields in my json values

Answer (score 0):

1-Make Entity class properties start with lowercase.
2-Check for Annotations.
3-Check for Constructor-->  **Entity classes should have two constructor.
4-Check for Getter and Setters.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, date format was given incorrectly