# Getting null values in Request Body

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest

I have my Controller class as

```
package com.example.test.Controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.test.Model.Example;



@RestController
public class Controller {
 
    @PostMapping("/produce")
    public void process1(@RequestBody Example example)
    {
        System.out.println(example);
    }
}
```

My Json request is as follow:

```
{
    "master_subscriber_id": 123456,
    "request_ts": "timestamp",
    "request_uuid": "123dfrg",
    "treatments": [{
            "treatement_cd": "dsad",
            "offer_id": "dsads",
            "offer_type": "ds"
        },
        {
            "treatement_cd": "dsad",
            "offer_id": "dsad",
            "offer_type": "dsa"
        },
        {
            "treatement_cd": "tro_12345",
            "offer_id": "xyz_34567",
            "offer_type": "XYZ"
        }
    ]
}
```

My Model Classes are as follow:

```
package com.example.test.Model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Example {

    private Integer masterSubscriberId;

    private String requestTs;

    private String requestUuid;
    
    private List<Treatment> treatments= new ArrayList<Treatment>() ;

    public Integer getMasterSubscriberId() {
        return masterSubscriberId;
    }

    public void setMasterSubscriberId(Integer masterSubscriberId) {
        this.masterSubscriberId = masterSubscriberId;
    }

    public String getRequestTs() {
        return requestTs;
    }

    public void setRequestTs(String requestTs) {
        this.requestTs = requestTs;
    }

    public String getRequestUuid() {
        return requestUuid;
    }

    public Example() {
        super();
    }

    public void setRequestUuid(String requestUuid) {
        this.requestUuid = requestUuid;
    }

    public List<Treatment> getTreatments() {
        return treatments;
    }

    public void setTreatments(List<Treatment> treatments) {
        this.treatments = treatments;
    }

    public Example(Integer masterSubscriberId, String requestTs, String requestUuid, List<Treatment> treatments) {
        super();
        this.masterSubscriberId = masterSubscriberId;
        this.requestTs = requestTs;
        this.requestUuid = requestUuid;
        this.treatments = treatments;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Example [masterSubscriberId=" + masterSubscriberId + ", requestTs=" + requestTs + ", requestUuid="
                + requestUuid + ", treatments=" + treatments + "]";
    }
    
}

package com.example.test.Model;

public class Treatment {

    private String treatementCd;

    private String offerId;

    private String offerType;

    public String getTreatementCd() {
        return treatementCd;
    }

    public void setTreatementCd(String treatementCd) {
        this.treatementCd = treatementCd;
    }

    public String getOfferId() {
        return offerId;
    }

    public void setOfferId(String offerId) {
        this.offerId = offerId;
    }

    public String getOfferType() {
        return offerType;
    }

    public void setOfferType(String offerType) {
        this.offerType = offerType;
    }

    public Treatment() {
        super();
    }

    public Treatment(String treatementCd, String offerId, String offerType) {
        super();
        this.treatementCd = treatementCd;
        this.offerId = offerId;
        this.offerType = offerType;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Treatment [treatementCd=" + treatementCd + ", offerId=" + offerId + ", offerType=" + offerType + "]";
    }

    
}
```

My output is coming like this
Example [masterSubscriberId=null, requestTs=null, requestUuid=null, treatments=[Treatment [treatementCd=null, offerId=null, offerType=null], Treatment [treatementCd=null, offerId=null, offerType=null], Treatment [treatementCd=null, offerId=null, offerType=null]]].

Comment: Your JSON doesn't match the names of the properties. So either change the names of the properties or switch to the proper naming strategy in Jackson to match your snake_case naming strategy.

Comment: Ohhhh i see now.I used Json to pojo convertor and didn't notice about attributes.Thanks a lot:)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not use additional annotations, the key-names in Json must match attribute names in Java classes. So in your case "master_subscriber_id" in JSON must be replaced with "masterSubscriberId" as it is in your `Example` class.

Or you can use this annotation `@JsonProperty("master_subscriber_id")` in your `Example` class for the mapping.

In my German blog I have written some articles about this topic: 
https://agile-coding.blogspot.com/2020/10/rest-json-apis-in-java-leicht-gemacht.html

Comment: For some reason, even though the names in Java class and JSON property were identical, I still got `null`. `@JsonProperty` was the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per my observation, it is not an issue with the JSON or Lombok like others might suggest.

**Make sure you are using exact same variable names in your Entity class and the DTO class.**

Example:

My Entity Class (`Event.java`):

```
package com.fest.app.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;

@Data
@Builder
@Table(name = "events")
public class Event {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String description;
}
```

My DTO (`EventDTO.java`):

```
package com.fest.app.controller.dto;

public record EventDTO(Long id, String name, String description) {
}
```

I am using Java 17 and Lombok. I did not face any issues apart from the concern that I have mentioned above.

Hope it helps!