# spring boot Issues with declaration

Tags: spring-boot

> i am trying to declare produits in the request
> this request contains the name, address ... and the product inside of it there are many objects as shown her

> produits: Array(3)
> 0: {idProduits: "60823e87db0f3a2c4cfedaed", nameprduits: "mini Airbus A330", prixprduits: 16.5, quantitep: 2, total: undefined, …}
> 1: {idProduits: "60823e87db0f3a2c4cfedaec", nameprduits: "VELOCIRAPTOR", prixprduits: 50, quantitep: 2, total: undefined, …}
> 2: {idProduits: "60823e87db0f3a2c4cfedaeb", nameprduits: "mini VELOCIRAPTOR", prixprduits: 18, quantitep: 2, total: undefined, …}

> i triyed List<List> , List ,List , Object ...

> my request : facture
> adresse: "tunis / benarous"
> livraison: 7
> nom: "medbaha1"
> produits: Array(3)
> 0: {idProduits: "60823e87db0f3a2c4cfedaed", nameprduits: "mini Airbus A330", prixprduits: 16.5, quantitep: 2, total: undefined, …}
> 1: {idProduits: "60823e87db0f3a2c4cfedaec", nameprduits: "VELOCIRAPTOR", prixprduits: 50, quantitep: 2, total: undefined, …}
> 2: {idProduits: "60823e87db0f3a2c4cfedaeb", nameprduits: "mini VELOCIRAPTOR", prixprduits: 18, quantitep: 2, total: undefined, …}
> length: 3
> **proto**: Array(0)
> siege: "marsa"
> tel: "50140787"
> total: 176
> totalht: 142.01680672268907
> totaltva: 26.98319327731093
> **proto**: Object

and thanks

Comment: I am sorry. Not clear with your question to answer

Comment: I am sending a requests that contain facture body like the name and number  total cost and it it contains a list of products I don't know how to declare this entity.  This is the body of products             produits: idProduits: "60823e87db0f3a2c4cfedaed", nameprduits: "mini Airbus A330", prixprduits: 16.5, quantitep: 2, total: undefined, …} 1: {idProduits: "60823e87db0f3a2c4cfedaec", nameprduits: "VELOCIRAPTOR", prixprduits: 50, quantitep: 2, total: undefined, …} 2: {idProduits: "60823e87db0f3a2c4cfedaeb", nameprduits: "mini VELOCIRAPTOR", prixprduits: 18, quantitep: 2, total: undefined, …}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is my understanding.

```
name: 'aaa'
totalCost: 500
produits[
    0 {idProduits: "60823e87db0f3a2c4cfedaed", nameprduits: "mini Airbus A330", prixprduits: 16.5, quantitep: 2, total: undefined, …} 
    1: {idProduits: "60823e87db0f3a2c4cfedaec", nameprduits: "VELOCIRAPTOR", prixprduits: 50, quantitep: 2, total: undefined, …} 
    2: {idProduits: "60823e87db0f3a2c4cfedaeb", nameprduits: "mini VELOCIRAPTOR", prixprduits: 18, quantitep: 2, total: undefined, …}
]
```

If the above one is your request means , you may need a two entity with fields something like below,
**Entity.class**

```
Private String name;
Private long totalCost;
private List<Produits> produitsList;
```

**Produits.class**

```
private String idProduits:
private String nameprduits;
private Long/Float prixprduits;
private int quantitep;
private int total;
```

Comment: Every thing get results of null

Comment: Can you post your entity file ?

Comment: Document(collection = "facture")
public class facture {
    @Id
    private String idFacture;
    private  String nom;
    
    private String adresse;
    private String tel;
    private String siege;
    private List<Produitsdefacture> produits;
    private int totaltva;
    private int totalht;
    private int total;
    private int livraison;

    public void setStatu(boolean statu) {
        this.statu = statu;
    }

    public boolean isStatu() {
        return statu;
    }

    private boolean statu=false;

Comment: public class Produitsdefacture {
    @Id
    private String idproduitsfacture;
    private String nameprduits;
    private Float prixprduitsHT;
    private Float prixprduitsTVA;
    private Float prixprduits;
    private int quantitep;
    private int totalproduit;

Comment: Below are the possible reasons you getting null values.
1. Create Getter and Setter using lambok / corresponding setter getter methods for your fields. 
2. And also make sure , first char of fields are lowercase. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38939812/7485135
3. Check the field name in entity matches with your request fields that may comes from front end side. If not, you can bind variables with @JSONProperty