# PostMapping request body shows Null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

### Issue with @RequestBody mapping to null in Spring Boot API

While building an e-commerce application, I encountered a problem with my cart API. The API seems to be working perfectly; however, the `@RequestBody` annotation is mapping my DTO object to null. I've provided the relevant code snippets below:

```java
@Data
public class AddProductInCartDto {
    private Long userId;
    private Long productId; 
    
}
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/customer")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CartController {
    private final CartService cartService;
    
    @PostMapping("/cart")
    public ResponseEntity<?> addProductToCart(@RequestBody AddProductInCartDto addProductInCartDto) {
        System.out.println("Received payload: " + addProductInCartDto);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(addProductInCartDto);
//      return cartService.addProductToCart(addProductInCartDto);
    }
}
```

SpringBoot colsole  Output

```java
Received payload: AddProductInCartDto(userId=null, productId=null)
```

[Postman Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7sHp.png)

I have explicitly mentioned `"application/json"` in the header, and I also added `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` in `@PostMapping`. Interestingly, the GET mapping to the same URL is working fine.

Could anyone please help me identify the reason behind this issue and suggest potential solutions? Any insights or debugging tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@RequestBody is getting null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935912/requestbody-is-getting-null-values)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @eol , such a silly mistake. My IDE Imported from swagger RequestBody , and as eclipse hides imports i couldn't notice

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion would be to **Check the DTO Class.** Verify that your AddProductInCartDto class has appropriate getter and setter methods. Spring uses these methods to convert JSON content into Java objects.

You can use **[Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/)** for getter and setter methods, or you can generate them manually.

Comment: If you checked the code he already uses Lombok.